# Getting "InputStream: cannot search backwards." when reading compressed Avro file from S3 on Flink

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-flink

I am currently learning Flink and I my goal is to read an Avro encoded and gzipped file from S3, then process its contents.

I managed to make it work for uncompressed files (`.avro` extensions), but when I point to a `.gz` extension I get the following exception:

```
2022-08-12 15:51:21,418 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Split Reader: Custom File Source -> Map -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (1/1)#0 (bcd4507e1eac498d2c2fea1c4785679e) switched from RUNNING to FAILED with failure cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrapped InputStream: cannot search backwards.
```

The code that I am using is this:

```java
public class StreamingJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // String path = "s3a://my-test-bucket/tweets.avro"; // <-- this works fine
        String path = "s3a://my-test-bucket/tweets.gz";

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        AvroInputFormat inputFormat = new AvroInputFormat<TwitterSchema>(
            new Path(path), 
            TwitterSchema.class
        );

        DataStreamSource<TwitterSchema> ds = env.readFile(
            inputFormat,
            path,
            FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY,
            10000l, // 10 seconds
            TypeInformation.of(TwitterSchema.class)
        );

        ds
            .map(t -> t.getTweet())
            .print();

        env.execute("s3 job example");
    }
}
```

I assume that Flink will be able to decompress the file just fine based on the section [Read compressed files](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/batch/#read-compressed-files) of their documentation.

Versions I am using:

```
<flink.version>1.14.5</flink.version>
<target.java.version>1.8</target.java.version>
```

Comment: The documentation you've pointed to is for the DataSet API for Flink version 1.4, but you're using the DataStream API with Flink 1.14. The connectors for DataSet and DataStream are completely different.

Comment: You shouldn't be compressing Avro with gzip in the first place. Instead, use one of the compression codecs (e.g., deflate) when saving the file.